# Move uploaded images to a folder using custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom, varien-file-uploader

> I am trying to move the uploaded image to a folder by a custom module.

In `/var/www/html/magento16f/app/code/local/Custommodule/ReviewRating/controllers/IndexController.php`

```
public function move_uploadedFileAction( ) {
    Mage::log($_FILES);

    $path = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/uploadfolder';
    Mage::log( $path );
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        mkdir($path, 777, true);
    }
    try {
        $fname = $_FILES['unverified-images']['name'];
        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('unverified-images');
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('png', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'docx'));
        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $uploader->save($path, $fname);
        Mage::log( $uploader );

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error Message: ' . $e->getMessage();

    }

   $this->_redirectReferer();

  }
```

In `/var/www/html/magento16f/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/reviewrating/signupformhb.phtml`

```
''''''''''''''''''''''
   <input type="file"  multiple="multiple" name="unverified-images" value="Upload" />

 '''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

This function calls a js function which trigger some api on sussess of api return i want to move the uploaded images to a folder and then share the link.

In `js file i call below function`

```
  function write_review() {  
    var form = document.getElementById('hb_writereview_user');
    var url = "http://somewebsite.com?api";
    var params = form.serialize();
    httpRequest (params, url, 'POST', function (response) {    
        if(response.error) {
            document.getElementById('hb_show_message_review').innerHTML=response.message;
        } else {
                uploadFileHb(params);

        }
    });
}
```

In  `/var/www/html/magento16f/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/reviewrating/signupformhb.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

function uploadFileHb( myFileObject ) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Open our connection using the POST method
    xhr.open("POST", "<?php echo $this->getUrl('reviewrating/index/move_uploadedFile') ?>");

    // Send the file
    xhr.send(myFileObject);
}
```

> I am not getting log (Mage::log) from controller

Answer (score 0):

> try to use bellow code

```
public function move_uploadedFileAction() {
    if (isset($_FILES['unverified-images']['name']) && $_FILES['unverified-images']['name'] != '') {
        try {
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'mymodule' . DS .'model'.DS;
            if (!file_exists($path)) {
                mkdir($path, 777, true);
            }
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('unverified-images');
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $destFile = $path.$_FILES['unverified-images']['name'];
            $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
            $uploader->save($path, $filename);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to upload it in some folder may be at root so that i can share that link

Comment: is it possible to share the images from model folder ?